# Function of memory block in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

Today I started learning Simulink, and think I can wrap my head around it. However, I came to the definition of the definition of the "Memory Block":

Definition: The Memory block holds and delays its input by one major integration time step.

I don't really understand what that means. I understand that converting from a continuous to discrete time is a very useful thing (and from what I understand, a "zero order hold" is the way to do this), but the use of a memory block as defined above is rather confusing to me.

Can someone explain in layman's terms what it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If operating discretely and set to "inherit sample time", it works very similar to the (IMO) more superior unit delay block:

Input...: `6, 4, 8, 3, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0...`

Output: `0, 6, 4, 8, 3, 9, 1, 0, 0...`

If using continuous time, it delays equal to the time of one "integration step", which depends on your mathematical solver.

Unit delays are common for discrete systems; e.g., a [FIR filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response).

Comment: Does having a zero at the first one there in the delayed sequence introduce any big error in general?

Comment: Generally no. Most filters/systems need time for the data to populate through and fully "charge" up.